# Python | AsyncIO | TypeError: a coroutine was expected

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying python coroutine programming using asyncio. This is my code.

```
import asyncio

async def coro_function():
    return 2 + 2

async def get():
    return await coro_function()

print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(get))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
a1 = loop.create_task(get)
loop.run_until_complete(a1)
```

But when I execute it, it gives me error

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 13, in <module>
    a1 = loop.create_task(get)
  File "/home/alie/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 405, in create_task
    task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self)
TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <function get at 0x7fe1280b6c80>
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're passing in the function `get`.

In order to pass in a coroutine, pass in `get()`.

```
a1 = loop.create_task(get())
loop.run_until_complete(a1)
```

Take a look at the types:

```
>>> type(get)
<class 'function'>
>>> print(type(get()))
<class 'coroutine'>
```

`get` is a coroutine *function*, i.e. a function that returns a coroutine object, `get()`. For more information and a better understanding of the fundamentals, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't realize python was expecting a call to the function, rather than just the function object itself.