# Dynamically add coroutine in Python aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, aiohttp

I'm trying to use aiohttp REST interface to dynamically add bots that establish Websocket connection to target server, i.e., when the user wants to create a WS bot, he/she could use `curl -X POST <server>/bot` to create a new bot and then the bot will connect to a specific target Websocket server.
I'm trying to add the newly create WS connection into the main event loop which serves REST interface, but looks like doesn't work. I must miss something but I can't figure it out.

Below is the REST interface implementation:

```
botCenter = wsBotCenter()

@routes.post('/bot')
async def new_bot(request):
    await botCenter.new_bot()
    return web.Response(text="Ok\n")

app = web.Application()
app.on_startup.append(botCenter.start_loop)
app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

botCenter is a set contains all bots, it's implementation is like this:

```
class wsBotCenter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 1
        self.botDict = {}
        self.url = "ws://localhost:9001"
        self.app = None

    async def start_loop(self, app):
        self.app = app

    async def new_bot(self):
        bot = wsBot(self.url)
        self.botDict[self.id] = bot
        self.app[f"bot_{self.id}"] = self.app.loop.create_task(bot.start)
        self.id += 1
```

Bot is implemented like below:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession

class wsBot:
    def __init__(self, URL):
        self.url = URL
        self.session = ClientSession()

    async def start(self):
        await self.session.ws_connect(self.url)
        while True:
            msg = await self.session.receive()
            print(f"Rx {msg}")
```

I assume once I send `curl -X POST <server>/bot`, then there will be a coroutine created an added into the main event loop, then the coroutine starts establishing WS connection and receive the message.

However, I can not see a new WS connection is created even the new bot instance is created.

Could someone give me some advice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After replace `bot.start` with `bot.start()` then it works.

`bot.start()` is the coroutine.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975914/python-asyncio-typeerror-a-coroutine-was-expected/63975963