# A coroutine was expected, got None - when all tasks run ok (asyncio)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I get the error: "a coroutine was expected, got None" when running this code:

```
from led_notification import LedNotification
from enums import NotificationState
import asyncio

async def main():

    led = LedNotification()
    print("notification start")
    await led.notify(NotificationState.START)
    mute_notification = asyncio.create_task(led.notify(NotificationState.MUTE))                    
    await asyncio.sleep(3) 
    is_cancelled = mute_notification.cancel()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)     
    print(is_cancelled)    
    await asyncio.sleep(0)     
    try:
        led_off = asyncio.create_task(led.off()) 
        await led_off               
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


asyncio.run(main())
```

The output is as follows:

1. Notifies correctly for the START notification.
2. Correctly notifies for the MUTE task (infinite loop - blinking LED)
3. The MUTE task is cancelled.
4. The LED task runs and switches the LEDs off
5. Error "a coroutine was expected, got None" received

I'm not sure why the exception is being thrown when explicitly defining the led_off task as per other tasks and the led_off task executes successfully?

Comment: Have a look at [Python | AsyncIO | TypeError: a coroutine was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975914/python-asyncio-typeerror-a-coroutine-was-expected)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this helps, as I'm passing the function in correctly when creating tasks.

Comment: What is `led.off`? Surely it should be an `async` function?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the cause of the issue.

It was the offending led.off() function, it was successful in being called, however, wasn't prefixed with async, e.g. async def off(self):

Thank you quamrana for the prompt.